# Loading Page with fade out effect

Tags: javascript, fadeout

I would like to insert a fade-out effect after a timeout.
I read how to insert fade-out but I can't insert it in my code.

```js
(function() {
  if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("load", nascondi_loading_screen, false);
  } else {
    window.attachEvent("onload", nascondi_loading_screen);
  }
})();

function mostra_loading_screen() {
  document.getElementById("loading_screen").style.display = 'block';
}

function nascondi_loading_screen() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("loading_screen").style.display = 'none';
  }, 3000);
}

mostra_loading_screen();
```

```css
#loading_screen {
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 100px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
```

```html
<div id="loading_screen">
  <img class="uk-position-center" src="images/loader.gif">
</div>
```

Comment: you cant animate diplay none , use opacity instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An element is either displayed or not. You cant have a transition on that. However you could fade out by animating the opacity. For that set the opacity in js:

```
 document.getElementById("loading_screen").style.opacity = 0 /* or 1 to fade in */;
```

And then set a transition in css on that property:

```
 #loading_screen {
   transition: opacity ease 2s;
 }
```

Comment: @nope your edit suggests that you just copy+pasted my code without trying to understand it. Please check more carefully the next time before downvoting :)

Comment: @JonasW. Indeed I copy-pasted it as so would OP :) and yes my CSS sucks so I failed to notice the comment. Apologies. Feel free to edit back off course I just needed/wanted to change my vote :)

Comment: @nope no im fine with that :) i always try to answer so that it is not copy+pasteable so that the OP has to read it...

Comment: @Nope Hi, I'm new on stackoverflow, and I would like to understand your change to my question: why did you remove some text? do you think it is not useful? and how did you color the code? Thank you

Comment: @JonasW. Hello jonas, thank you very much for your reply, I thought I had solved it, but now I have a new problem. The div becomes invisible because the opacity goes to 0, but still remains above the page, and prevents me from clicking on the links. how do I use both the fade out and the display state?

Comment: @Lorenzo There is no right or wrong (I think) but when I edit a question to format the code I usually try to also remove any "clutter" and format the text to focus on the issue. I'm kind of in-line with the believe of [**this post**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/163052) - I suppose its subjective I guess and please feel free to edit things back which ever way you see fit.

Comment: @lorenzo you could also fade out the `height` property in a similar way

Answer (score 0):

JonasW.
In the end I solved this way, so that after 3 seconds I change the opacity, and after another 2 (5 total) puts me display none.

```
                   function nascondi_loading_screen()   {
       setTimeout(function() { 
           document.getElementById("loading_screen").style.opacity = 0;
                             }, 3000);

                setTimeout(function(){ 
                    document.getElementById("loading_screen").style.display = 'none'; }, 5000);

}
```